# Why is MongoDB not using the right index?

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB query that I'm trying to optimize. I created an index that matches the fields in the query, but I can't seem to get MongoDB's query planner to use the index without an explicit `hint()`, even though the `nscanned` and `milli`s are better for the hinted version.

Here are the indexes, the query (with and without the hint), and a verbose explain:

http://paste.roguecoders.com/p/4face5649612e840da04c5fea0491c9b.txt

One additional bit of info: this index is in a large-ish collection, in a replica set, so I built the index using the [offline method](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/build-indexes-on-replica-sets/). It's now present in all nodes.

(Originally posted on [MongoDB-User](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongodb-user/NzBmHqpF_JQ).)

Comment: What if you made the index: `owner_1_date_-1_from_backup_1`?

Comment: My index is right. I'm sorting on `date`. (And the `hint()` confirms that it's better.) It also takes over an hour to index this collection on our production dataset, so I'm not willing to just try things without a good reason. (-:

Comment: This link may explain why you are getting `scanAndOrder` http://blog.mongolab.com/2012/06/cardinal-ins/ it may also explain why MongoDb is not seeing your created index as optimal

Comment: what version of MongoDB are you using?  Also, can you include your index stats?

Comment: @Sammaye it might indeed be related to `scanAndOrder`. Thanks for the heads-up on that. I'll poke at it.

Comment: This is MongoDB 2.4.2, FWIW (@AsyaKamsky)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be to a regression in 2.4 which affects SERVER-5063 fix when one of the values in the {$in:[ ]} clause is "null".  I filed it as new ticket https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9495 which I hope will be triaged and fixed soon.

Meanwhile, depending on why there are null values (or absence of field?) along with true/false you have several options, some involving changing the query some changing the data.  I would not advise downgrading to 2.2 just for that, but it's also a possibility.